# Проблема с адаптивной версткой

Tags: css

Как бороться с зачеркнутыми значениями при адаптивной верстке? Если в медиа выражении на какое-то определенное разрешение экрана ставишь такой-то фонт сайз, то оно не работает, потому что на десктопной версии стоит другой. Как это исправить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы прописали десктопные стили после мобильных, а надо прописывать мобильные стили после десктопных, приоритет зависит от порядка стилей в файле

Comment: Любые медиа-запросы должны описываться в самом конце файла, после обычных стилей и никак иначе.

Comment: Спасибо большое за подробный ответ)

Answer (score 3):

Стили применяются к элементу сверху вниз, то есть сначала применяется из блока media, а потом уже переопределяется из строки 84, поэтому общий стиль нужно указывать сверху, а какие то кастомные ниже в порядке их применения.
Important не желательно применять, это уже когда совсем опустились руки и нужно здесь и сейчас))